# Dimension isnt working in xiaomi phones? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio, expo

Im building a component that show some icons so the user can choose the color, the component is just a `<View>` and inside of it theres a `flatlist` showing the icons: heres the code:

```
class Color extends Component {
    
    icons_config = {name: "square-full", size: 80, color: "black"};
    show_hide_ = false;
    options_array = [
        {option_icon: <FontAwesome5 name = {this.icons_config.name} size = {this.icons_config.size} color = "red"/>, key: "red"}, 
        {option_icon: <FontAwesome5 name = {this.icons_config.name} size={this.icons_config.size}  color = "blue"/>, key: "blue"}, 
        {option_icon: <FontAwesome5 name = {this.icons_config.name} size={this.icons_config.size}  color = "green"/>, key: "green"}, 
        {option_icon: <FontAwesome5 name = {this.icons_config.name} size={this.icons_config.size}  color = "yellow"/>, key: "yellow"},
        {option_icon: <FontAwesome5 name = {this.icons_config.name} size={this.icons_config.size}  color = "purple"/>, key: "purple"},
        {option_icon: <FontAwesome5 name = {this.icons_config.name} size={this.icons_config.size}  color = "black"/>, key: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"},
        {option_icon: <FontAwesome5 name = {this.icons_config.name} size={this.icons_config.size}  color = "gray"/>, key: "gray"},
        {option_icon: <FontAwesome5 name = {this.icons_config.name} size={this.icons_config.size}  color = "orange"/>, key: "orange"},
        {option_icon: <AntDesign name="closesquareo" size={80} color="black" />, key: ""}, //x icon for delete color
    ];
    window_width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    window_height = Dimensions.get("window").height;

    render() { 
        return (
            <>
                <View style = {this.styles.container}>
                    {this.options_array.map((option) => {
                        return (
                            <View key = {option.key} style = {this.styles.options}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style = {this.styles.touchable} onPress = {() => this.choose_color(option.key)}>
                                <Text>{option.option_icon}</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        );
                    })}
                </View>
            </>
        );
    }
```

and the stylesheet code:

```
styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        position: "absolute",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        width: Math.round(this.window_width) * 0.8, 
        height: Math.round(this.window_width) * 0.8,
        flexWrap: "wrap",
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignSelf: "center",
        //backgroundColor: "#DCDCDC",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        marginTop: 200,
    }, 
    options: {
        paddingTop: Math.round(this.window_width) * 0.025,
        justifyContent: "center",
    }
});
```

the problem now, is that im using `Dimensions.get("window").width` in `width and height` to create a responsive square for all devices, the problem is that it isnt working in my xiaomi mi 9T, but it does in my one plus 7 pro and on my huawei p9 plus, here Im goint to post some captures so you can see it:

Xiaomi mi 9t:

[image]

One plus 7 pro:

[image]

Huawei p9 plus:

[image]

I guess it has something to do with the icons size, but for one plus and huawei theres no problem, how can I solve this?

Comment: Can you make sure whether `Dimensions.get("window").width;` is failing or `width: Math.round(this.window_width) * 0.8, ` this is.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the screen width or height using window prop and set the card width and height.

Following example will help you,

```
 import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
    
    const window = Dimensions.get('window');

    styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container: {
         width: (window.width) * 0.8,
         height: (window.width) * 0.8
    }, 
   
});
```

Comment: @plus if this answer is acceptable please accept this answer and close the question

Comment: Isn't this the same logic used in the question?